# What properties do I need to assume such that the integral is finite?

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I have the following integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty |x f(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x.
$$

What are sufficient properties I can assume my function $f$ to have such that so that the integral is finite? All I could think of was compact support of $f$. However, this is a very restrictive assumption. I think something like rapid decay may also be enough but I'm not sure about that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could ask the same question for $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm dx$ for $g\ge0,$ and then translate the condition on $g(x):=x^2|f(x)|^2$ into a condition on $f.$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but how would that change the problem?

Comment: There are a lot of sufficient conditions one could make, mostly by using the comparison test with some other function where the integral is known to converge.

Comment: The question almost sounds like this: When is a function integrable? It is too broad  a question to be called meaningful.

Comment: Continuous and $|f| \in O(x^{-r})$ for some $r > \frac 32$ is sufficient, but not necessary.